# How to change server vanity url with discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

As it says in the title, how can I change it with discord.js? I want to change using api v8 or using discord bot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because only guilds with level 3 can set a vanity URL, you can only set a vanity URL through the official Discord app. However you can recieve a guilds vanity URL with the following link: [https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/{guild-id}/vanity-url](https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/%7Bguild-id%7D/vanity-url). Assuming your bot has `MANAGE_GUILD` permissions and you define the `Authorization` header.